# Adding values to missing nodes in binary tree using Python

Tags: python-2.7, binary-tree

I have the following binary tree:

```
..............1
............/....\
...........2......3
........../..\......\
.........4....5.....6
..........\........./
...........8.......7
```

I would to complete it to a full binary tree by adding (-1) to the nodes that are missing and to get line by line.
It means that the tree will look like this:

```
..............1
............/.....\
...........2.........3
........../..\....../..\
.........4....5....-1.....6
......../.\.../\..../.\../.\
......-1...8.-1.-1.-1.-1.7.-1
```

The required result will be as followed:

```
1
2 3
4 5 -1 6
-1 8 -1 -1 -1 -1 7 -1
```

The code for creating the binary tree is:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,val):
        self.val = val
        self.left = None
        self.right = None



root =  Node(1)
root.left = Node(2)
root.right = Node(3)
root.left.left = Node(4)
root.left.right = Node(5)
root.right.left = Node(6)
root.right.left.left = Node(7)
root.left.left.right = Node(8)
```

Comment: Recursively iterate the tree, check whether left is null and current node value not -1, create and add a node at the left. Do same for the right.

Comment: Please refer the comments in the answer, you can easily fix the new line issue in the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only thing is you have to determine the `level` first and pass it. However, this also can be handled.
Fill missing nodes:

```
def fillMissingNodes(root, level):
    if (root == None):
        return
    if(root.left == None and level > 0):
        root.left = Node(-1)
    if(root.right == None and level > 0):
        root.right = Node(-1)
    fillMissingNodes(root.left, level - 1)
    fillMissingNodes(root.right, level - 1)

fillMissingNodes(root, 3)
```

Now, you can traverse in any way you want. Here is level order traversing using Queue:

```
def traverseLevelOrder(q):
    while(q.qsize() > 1):
        current = q.get()
        if(current == None):
            q.put(None)
            print("\n")
        else:
            if(current.left != None):
                q.put(current.left)
            if(current.right != None):
                q.put(current.right)
            print(current.val),

traverseLevelOrder(q)
```

In case you want to combine filling missing nodes and traversal line order here you go:

```
def traverseLevelOrderAndFillMissingNodes(q, level):
    while(q.qsize() > 1):
        current = q.get()
        if(current == None):
            q.put(None)
            print("\n")
            level = level - 1
        else:
            if(current.left == None and level > 0):
                current.left = Node(-1)
            if(current.right == None and level > 0):
                current.right = Node(-1)
            if(current.left != None):
                q.put(current.left)
            if(current.right != None):
                q.put(current.right)
            print(current.val),


traverseLevelOrderAndFillMissingNodes(q, 3)
```

Here is the output:

```
1 
2 3 
4 5 -1 6 
-1 8 -1 -1 -1 -1 7 -1
```

Refer to the full running example [from github](https://github.com/fiveobjects/reference/blob/master/python/57239462-FillMissingNodeAndPrintLevelOrder.py)

By the way, you tree creation code is not exactly like you have shown in the diagram. There is a minor issue with left and right (look for 6 and 7 addition). Here is the correct one:

```
root = Node(1)
root.left = Node(2)
root.right = Node(3)
root.left.left = Node(4)
root.left.right = Node(5)
root.right.right = Node(6)
root.right.right.left = Node(7)
root.left.left.right = Node(8)
```

Comment: Is there a way to create a function with no need to send the level as parameter (just q)?